# SAS - Creating smaller datasets from a bigger one iteratively based on the distinct values of a certain column

Tags: sas

I have a huge dataset with a column(variable) having 100 distinct values. I want to break this dataset into 100 smaller parts using those distinct values of the column and that too in a loop(iteratively). I have been suggested to use a macro but i'm unable to do that

Comment: What is the value domain of your selection criterion: integers, strings of limited length or something else?

Comment: What is your overall goal here? Generally in SAS it is a Bad Idea to split a large dataset into lots of smaller ones, as it involves writing much more complex code.

Comment: http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2015/01/26/how-to-split-one-data-set-into-many/

Comment: You should post what you've tried, SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 1):

**Sollution with macro variables only**: list your datasets and output statements in a proc sql with an into clause:

```
proc sql;
    select distinct 'WORK.cars_'|| origin
         , 'when ("'|| trim(origin) ||'") output cars_'|| origin
    into   :cars_data separated by ' '
         , :cars_when separated by '; '
    from   sashelp.cars;
quit;
```

Leave out the double quotes for an integer criterion.
For a float criterion, convert the dot to an underscore.

```
data &cars_data.;
    set sashelp.cars;
    select (origin);
        &cars_when.;
    end;
run;
```